# Not able to find an iframe in Java and Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

[image]

When I try to find iframe I am not able to find it, can any try to help me please? I tried for

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//iframe[contains(@src,'RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887')]"));
```

but it's not working. I get this error:

> org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@src,'RLCommonControls/LeftNavig‌​ation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887')]"}

My HTML:

```
<tr>
   <td valign="top" style="width: 200px; height: 832px;" data-ig="x:897723063.1:adr:0" adr="0">
      <div class="gradientExplorer igspl_Office2007BluePane" style="height: 832px; overflow: hidden; border-style: none; width: 200px;" clientid="RL_SplitterPane_Navigation" data-ig="x:897723063.2:mkr:c0" mkr="c0">
      <iframe frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" title="/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887"> <!DOCTYPE html> 
      <html>
         <head id="Head1">
```

Comment: what error are you getting or what problem are you facing ?

Comment: <tr>
<td valign="top" style="width: 200px; height: 832px;" data-ig="x:897723063.1:adr:0" adr="0">
<div class="gradientExplorer igspl_Office2007BluePane" style="height: 832px; overflow: hidden; border-style: none; width: 200px;" clientid="RL_SplitterPane_Navigation" data-ig="x:897723063.2:mkr:c0" mkr="c0">
<iframe frameborder="0" style="width:100%;height:100%;" title="/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head id="Head1">

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException:   Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//iframe[contains(@src,'RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887')]"}

Comment: please consider adding code snippet and error in the question itself

Comment: Add the required code in question. Click edit link below the question to [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35910734/edit) the question and add the required code.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath you can use:-

```
//iframe[@title='/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx']
```

OR

```
//iframe[@src='/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887']
```

OR more specific

```
//iframe[@title='/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx' and @src='/RLCommonControls/LeftNavigation.aspx?navMenuHeight=887']
```

If you want to switch to frame then you can do it like :-

```
WebElement frameele =driver.findElement(By.xpath("ANY XPATH FROM ABOVE"));

driver.switchTo().frame(frameele);
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score 0):

If its the first frame in the html just do:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

- if frame doesn't have name or id you can select it by index